# 3hp motor contactor size 22A or 40A?

Tags: current, motor, motor-controller, circuit-protection

So my place has 2 contactor sizes of 22A and 40A. Now i know that both will be more than enough to power up a 3HP motor. To avoid oversizing in this case, would i need to provide additional fusing to help protect the 3HP motor if it has a 40A contactor as opposed to a 22A?

This is 480V system that is sized for a 3hp motor ( electrical disconnect that is)

There is also a 40A overload to be used with this 40A contactor. It jus means the overload and contactor can handle up to 40A each

Basically it's a electrical disconnect like a fuse breaker (sized for a 3hp motor) u have a ol on the starter I dont think there is an ol on the breaker. Normally with < 5hp motor running at 480 your minimum circuit ampacity is <10A so either 20A contactor or 40A contactor is more then enough.

Comment: The answer depends on the voltage which is not specified in your question and you have no location information in your user profile so we don't know what country you are in. Hit the edit link...

Comment: Its 3phase 480V and the disconnect at the site is sized appropriately for the 3 phase motor.

Comment: When you say disconnect do you mean the branch breaker or an actual disconnect? Also, is there an overload on the branch?

Answer (score 2):

> To avoid oversizing in this case, would i need to provide additional fusing to help protect the 3HP motor if it has a 40A contactor as opposed to a 22A?

No. Fuses are not for protecting the motor they are for protecting the wiring and other current-carrying components from short circuits and ground faults. They also prevent a fire if the motor or motor protection fails. An overload relay, motor protective circuit-breaker or temperature detecting device in the motor are the possible motor protective devices. The motor protective devices are always selected and adjusted based on the motor ratings, Hp & voltage, current or winding temperature.

> There is also a 40A overload to be used with this 40A contactor. It jus means the overload and contactor can handle up to 40A each

It does not just mean it can handle 40 amps. The 40A overload may not be appropriate. Some have interchangeable current sensing parts that allow a wide range of motors, and some are adjustable. However there is a limit to the range of motors for which they are appropriate. The documentation for the overload tells what motor voltage & power or current for which they can provide appropriate protection.

Comment: How would you adjust the 20A or 40A motor starter though? If your only load is a 3hp motor

Comment: You adjust some overload protection devices. You can not use a starter that is that large unless it has provisions for smaller motor protection or the protection is provided separately.

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

For more reliable motor protection, use the actual motor current as listed on the motor nameplate which ought to be around 5A.

Answer (score 0):

> Normally with < 5hp motor running at 480 your minimum circuit ampacity is <10A so either 20A contactor or 40A contactor is *more than enough*.

*More than enough* is not the problem when it comes to motor protection. We need to be concerned about **too much**. The pieces protecting the branch are the overload device (motor overheating) and the circuit breaker (short circuit, overload). The contactor provides control, and the disconnect provides a means of locking out the circuit. For the most part a general motor protection branch looks like the following:

[image: Motor protection branch circuit]

Assuming that:

- Disconnect is sized appropriately (if applicable),
- Circuit breaker/fuses are sized to protect downstream components,
- Wiring is rated for more than the circuit breaker/fuses, and
- Overload can be set for somewhere in the 6 A range (3 hp @ 480 VAC = 4.8 A)(4.8 A * 125% = 6 A)

The choice between a 22 A and 40 A contactor is moot. A contactor is a glorified switch and the ratings are for its own function. You want to avoid under-sizing a contactor, but you can oversize. Go with the 22 A, it will save a couple bucks. Keep the 40 A around for a 30 hp motor.

---

Notes:

- A 40 A overload may only be adjustable for something like 40 ... 60 A since it is designed for a 30 hp motor. 40 A minimum overload setting is not appropriate for a 3 hp motor.

Comment: Now let me ask you this if your disconnect is fused and the incoming line is sized for 3hp motor you wouldn't have to worry about extra fuses correct?

Comment: Yes. A fused disconnect can replace the disconnect+fusing in the above diagram. Assuming it is fused for the 3 hp branch only (10 A?). In that case, it would look like a fused disconnect feeding a contactor/OL pair, then to the motor.